# php error not displayed

Tags: php, apache2

I am new to php  ; when ever ther is some error in my script ,the browser do not display error  wirh line nymber but displays :

> Server error
>   The website encountered an error while retrieving "http://localhost/gmailAPP/google-api-php-client/examples/calendar/simple.php". It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
>   Here are some suggestions:
>   Reload this webpage later.
>   HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

It is very difficult to debug the code with out error message and line number .Please help

Answer (score 1):

write:

```
  <?php

    /**
     * Whether errors should be displayed
     */
    ini_set('display_errors', true);

    /**
     * Set the error reporting level
     */
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);  // display errors must be turned on

 ?>
```

and ensure that your .htaccess file has no failure (if you use one).

Note: error_reporting(ERROR_LEVEL) is an alias for the ini_set() method shown above.

Answer (score 1):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

or on your htaccess file

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the error log directly from the server with the following command

```
tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

or, to show the last 100 lines

```
tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

or to output appended data as the file grows

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

**You will need to verify the path of your error log, maybe it can change**

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on errors in config file

Answer (score 0):

Try this , put this line in beginning of your PHP file and Check , this is runtime configuration method

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```